# How to install latest version of fabric

Tags: fabric, apt-get

How do I install the latest version of fabric on debian? When calling

```
apt-get install fabric
```

version 0.9.1 is being installed. The most recent version is 1.4.3 though.

Comment: try $ sudo  pypm install fabric

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can install the latest version from PyPI using [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) or easy_install.

For example:

```
apt-get install python-setuptools  # for easy_install
easy_install pip
pip install fabric
```

Comment: also if fabric is already installed, you can use "pip install --upgrade fabric"

Comment: @huseyinalb - I get `pip: command not found`, even though I have fabric 0.9something installed

Comment: sudo might be helpful here! 0_0

Comment: virtualenv might be even more helpful :) but the question assumes it's ran under root...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-setuptools gcc
sudo easy_install pip
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev libffi-dev
sudo pip install six==1.6.0
sudo pip install fabric
```